# h1 text display differently on different browsers

Tags: html, css

hello am having different h1 sizes on different browsers, how can i fix this please

h1 text on chrome [h1 text on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgslb.png)
h1 text on firefox
[h1 text on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqDlw.png)

Comment: Browsers have different default appearance. Try specifying the exact appearance you want in css.

Comment: User agents can completely ignore your hints about presentation. As suggested in another comment, you might be able to tweak this hints a bit more with CSS, but at the end of the day a user agent is free to ignore anything you present to it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS to set the `font-size` so all browsers will use that value instead of their own defaults.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

There may be other properties that you need to reset to get consistent, cross-browser results.

Many sites will employ a third party reset CSS like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or write their own defaults.

Answer (score 0):

h1 tag is just pure html, so it is just semantic. HTML, as semantic, doesn't apply any styling. Browsers will always try to render "h" tags in a way that you can understand which ones are the most relevant, comparing it to the others. H1 will be bigger than h2 in every browser, but that doesn't mean they will appear exactly with the same sizes.

You need to apply your CSS to achieve the behaviour you want. Just keep in mind that html is only semantic, not styles :) usually we can insert a normalize or reset CSS code to our stylesheets, so that it resets browsers called user agent stylesheets. try to use a font-size property with the correct value on it. Good work!